# Can't install latest Zoom version

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, zoom-meeting

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have Zoom in version 5.04084598.0517. Zoom shows an update to be available, so I downloaded it from the web page, and opened the deb file with the software installer. What then shows up is the following:

[image]

So there is no "install" or "update" button. How do I install this latest version of Zoom?

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy zoom`

```
zoom:
  Installed: 5.0.408598.0517
  Candidate: 5.0.408598.0517
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.408598.0517 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: It is already installed.

Comment: but the version numbers are different? And the zoom App shows an update to be available if I check for available ones?

Comment: I had installed an older version by downloading the deb file from the official web page, and updated several times as described above (getting an update notification, downloading and installing the linked deb file from the web page)

Comment: Please show the output of two commands - `snap list | grep zoom` and `apt-cache policy zoom` .

Comment: `snap list | grep zoom` doesn't return anything. I have added the output of `apt-cache policy zoom` to the original post.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get upgrade zoom`

Comment: doesn't upgrade anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issues, in Ubuntu 20.04. This is what worked for me:

> Using the terminal
>
> 1. Download the DEB installer file from our [Download Center](https://zoom.us/download?os=linux)
> 2. Open the download location using a file manager.
> 3. Right click in the file manager and click Terminal or Open in Terminal to open the terminal in the current location.
> 4. Type in the following command and press Enter to run it.
>
> > `sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb`

Source: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux#h_89c268b4-2a68-4e4c-882f-441e374b87cb

**Note - Use `sudo apt --fix-broken install` in case some of the dependencies are tend to missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install latest Zoom version, you should prefer installing Zoom using Snap. Latest version listed are:

```
latest/stable 5.0.413237.0524
latest/edge   5.0.418682.0603
```

To do so, you need to remove the Zoom installed on your system.

```
sudo dpkg -r zoom_amd64
```

Then install Zoom using Snap.

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

That will install latest Zoom from stable channel.

If you prefer to install latest Zoom from edge channel, add `--channel=latest/edge`.

```
sudo snap install zoom-client --channel=latest/edge
```

Visit https://snapcraft.io/install/zoom-client/ubuntu#install for more information about the zoom-client package on Snap website.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this as an alternative. However, I still would like to understand why installing as I tried doesn't work even though it did work like this for several updates before

Comment: I guess you see the update from app's about page. Unfortunately the Ubuntu repository is not fast enough to give the latest update released by Zoom itself because of their policy. That's why the latest Zoom version provided in Ubuntu repository is behind the latest version released by the Zoom.

Comment: But I don't update from the Ubuntu repository, I directly download the deb file from the official web page

Comment: yes, that's the problem. your deb file has newer release than what is available in Ubuntu repository. That's why you don't see the update from APT, which use Ubuntu repository as source.

Comment: But for all updates before, I had simply downloaded the deb file, and executed it via the software center (I think). Shouldn't I be able to update this way?

Answer (score 1):

Another option that worked in my case Linux Ubutnu 20.04.

I saw the answer in official docs:

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux

1. Download the latest Zoom version here: https://zoom.us/download?os=linux
2. Install GDebi (if it was not installed yet)

   ```
   sudo apt install gdebi
   ```
3. Go to a folder where `zoom_amd64.deb` was downloaded
4. Right click ⇢ Open with Other application
5. Select GDebi Package Installer. Click Select.
   [image]
6. In Package Installer click to Install. (In my case Reinstall because it was already updated)
   [image]

Done.

Answer (score 1):

I've just clicked that red "Remove" button in OP's screenshot. Then when it is done being removed, open the file again with Software Installer. It now has an install option, you install, voila, new version. You need to exit Zoom (which oddly isn't necessary to "Remove" it) and start it again to get the new version running. It still logs me in automatically to the same account I was using, so that must be stored in some config directory or something that isn't wiped on remove.